# SQL instance specified is not supported by installed version of TFS

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have installed Team Foundation Server 2013 Update 5. I am already running MSSQL 2008 R2 and MSSQL 2012. But when I tried to install my TFS it gives the following error in **Readiness Check** for **Basic** Setup Wizard.

> TF255146: The SQL Server instance you specified (Pearlserver) is
>   version 10.0.1600.22, which is not supported by this version of Team
>   Foundation Server. For more information about supported versions of
>   SQL Server, visit
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd578592(v=vs.120).aspx

Before this I had TFS 2013 Update 2 which was running fine but out of nowhere it started giving following error on accessing it from my VS2013 Update 4:

> HTTP: 500 Internal Server Error

So then I uninstalled the previous version and installed the Update 5 but the Data Tier error mentioned above is continuously appearing. Then I installed MSSQL 2014 but the error is still there.

Comment: If a TFS instance starts giving errors, don't upgrade it in the hope of the error disappearing - you only risk ruining it more. Check the event log, find the underlying cause. Do you have backups?

Comment: I didnot lost any data bcoz I was just started to use TFS. But when I installed SQL 2014, it neither ask the authentication type from me nor the instance. So when TFS is configuring it get the instance of SQL2008.

Comment: @CodeCaster How to point TFS towards the instance of SQL 2014?? But SQL2014 installation didn't ask abt any instance

Comment: `10.0.something` means SQL Server 2008. `10.50.something` would be SQL Server 2008 R2. So you've misidentified what version of SQL Server you're running.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have 2008,2012,2014 SQL's.. Now plz tell me hoe to make TFS to use an instance of 2012 or 2014???